# Create invalidation for multiple AWS CloudFront distributions in a loop

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cli, buildspec

I have a list of CloudFront distributions that need to be invalidated. I have made the list using this command:-

```
dist_id=$(aws cloudfront list-distributions --query "DistributionList.Items[*].{id:Id,origin:Aliases.Items[0]}[?origin=='website1.com'||origin=='website2.com'||origin=='website3.com'].id" --output text)
```

Now the create-invalidation command expects only one string value for the distribution ID. How do I make it run for all of my distributions?
When I run `aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id  $dist_id --paths "/*"` it says that distributions 2 and 3 are unknown options.

I am using these commands from inside a `buildspec.yml` file in my React project.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a plain for-do loop:-

```
for varname in $dist_id; do aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id  $varname --paths "/*"; done
```